# I seem to have wrong Mac Ports after upgrading to Snow Leopard

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, macports

I upgraded recently to Snow Leopard but used Time Machine wich was in Leopard. Time Machine asked to copy everything from old machine and I said yes.

How I seem to be having trouble installing Ruby because of the libraries and when I try to upgrade the Mac ports it fails although I installed the latest mac ports software.

Any ideas?

```
sudo port upgrade -d outdated
Warning: Skipping upgrade since ncursesw 5.7_0 >= ncursesw 5.7_0, even though installed variants "" do not match "+darwin_10". Use 'upgrade --enforce-variants' to switch to the requested variants.
Warning: Skipping upgrade since ncurses 5.7_0 >= ncurses 5.7_0, even though installed variants "" do not match "+darwin_10". Use 'upgrade --enforce-variants' to switch to the requested variants.
--->  Computing dependencies for apr-util
--->  Configuring apr-util
Error: Target org.macports.configure returned: configure failure: shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_devel_apr-util/work/apr-util-1.3.9" && ./configure --prefix=/opt/local --with-apr=/opt/local/bin/apr-1-config --with-expat=/opt/local --with-iconv=/opt/local --with-berkeley-db=/opt/local/include:/opt/local/lib/db46 --without-mysql --without-pgsql --with-sqlite3=/opt/local " returned error 1
Command output: checking for -ldb... no
checking for Berkeley DB 2 in /opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib/db46... 
checking db2/db.h usability... no
checking db2/db.h presence... no
checking for db2/db.h... no
checking db.h usability... yes
checking db.h presence... yes
checking for db.h... yes
checking for db_open in -ldb2... no
checking db2/db.h usability... no
checking db2/db.h presence... no
checking for db2/db.h... no
checking db.h usability... yes
checking db.h presence... yes
checking for db.h... yes
checking for db_open in -ldb... no
checking for Berkeley DB 1.0.0 in /opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib/db46... 
checking db1/db.h usability... no
checking db1/db.h presence... no
checking for db1/db.h... no
checking db.h usability... yes
checking db.h presence... yes
checking for db.h... yes
checking for dbopen in -ldb1... no
checking for Berkeley DB 1 in /opt/local/include and /opt/local/lib/db46... 
checking db_185.h usability... no
checking db_185.h presence... no
checking for db_185.h... no
checking for Berkeley DB... not found
configure: error: Berkeley DB not found.

Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1
Before reporting a bug, first run the command again with the -d flag to get complete output.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do what it says and use the `--enforce-variants` option to rebuild your installed ports using the 10.6 default variants:

```
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port upgrade -u --enforce-variants installed
```

EDIT:  If you haven't already, you will also probably need to install the [MacPorts base files](http://www.macports.org/install.php) for 10.6 and then upgrade the ports.  There are detailed instructions [here](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration).

Comment: Thanks Ned for the answer. unfortunately I got the same error message :(

Comment: See EDIT for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have the wrong Macports.

If you change your operating system, e.g. from Leopard to Snow Leopard (but not from SL to Lion), you need to reinstall Macports from scratch. See the [Macports migration guide](http://trac.macports.org/wiki/Migration)